# Does hook have an effect on increasing the page load?

Tags: functions, hooks, actions

I have a personal website which uses WordPress.
for same changes on the theme, I can add manually codes on single.php.
Or I can write a hook for it.
for example, I want to add content on a specific single.php line.

```
// I made a action
function after_p(){
    do_action('after_p');
}
```

and then put it on single.php

```
             <?php after_p();?>
```

then I add some line and PHP files with add action on function.php

```
// Download Box
if (!function_exists('downloadbox')) :
    {
        function downloadbox()
        {
            if (function_exists('get_field'){
                 include('downloadbox.php');
            }
        }
    }
endif;
 add_action( 'after_p', 'tc_downloadbox' );

// adv
if (!function_exists('my_adv')) :
    {
        function my_adv()
        {
            echo '<div id="java-script-advs"></div>';
        }
    }
endif;
add_action( 'after_p', 'my_adv' );
```

As you guess I am a beginner I have a doubt this way is current?
I mean does use the unnecessary hook have effects on page loading?
because on my case I can simply add `include('downloadbox.php')` on single.php(on the line what I want). at the same for `echo '<div id="java-script-advs"></div>';`

Comment: The difference is that hooks allow third parties to hook into your code.  I guess less lines is generally more efficient if you’re basically looking to do the same thing with both methods.

Comment: PHP runs on the server so you haven't added additional HTTP requests, extra DB queries or anything that would slow your site down a measurable amount.  Less code is always better, however.  A simpler approach would replace the `do_action()` call with a direct function call to `dj_after_p()` that called for the include file and echo'd the .java-script-advs div.

Comment: Instead of using `after_p()` which runs `do_action('after_p')`, you could just do              `<?php do_action('after_p');?>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cost of those hooks themselves is negligble and statistically insignificant. It would take great effort to measure such a change in performance, and would not take up more than a millionth of the total runtime. **Unused hooks are not a performance concern.**

The real concern here is that unnecessary complexity has been added that will show in the future as technical debt. I also notice you've wrapped all your functions in `{}` then again in a function exists check, both of which aren't necessary